# Unity Framework Unit Testing undefined reference to "setUp" and "tearDown"

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, compiler-errors, unity-test-framework

I copied the simplest code from the [Unity for C Unit Testing library](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity) and set up a very basic test, which I copied and pasted from the site:

```
#include "unity/src/unity.h"

int main(void)
{
    UNITY_BEGIN();
    int a = 1;
    TEST_ASSERT( a == 1 ); //this one will pass
    TEST_ASSERT( a == 2 ); //this one will fail
    return UNITY_END();
}
```

What I typed into terminal:

```
gcc TestDumbExample.c ./unity/src/unity.c -o Test
```

I am getting this error message in Terminal:

```
/tmp/ccqgFGn8.o: In function `UnityDefaultTestRun':
unity.c:(.text+0x26af): undefined reference to `setUp'
unity.c:(.text+0x26ca): undefined reference to `tearDown' collect2:
error: ld returned 1 exit status

Unsure why this error is occurring and it has undefined references.
```

Answer (score 9):

Need to define setUp and tearDown in the file, i thought it was in unity.c

```
void setUp (void) {} /* Is run before every test, put unit init calls here. */
void tearDown (void) {} /* Is run after every test, put unit clean-up calls here. */
```

Answer (score 1):

The Unit Test Framework uses these functions like a constructor/destructor.  Since you are doing a simple test you can just define two empty functions with these names.

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar issue.

[image]

Solution:

1. Go to your "unity.c" file.
2. Search for "void setUp(void);"

[image]

-> Replace the semicolon with parenthesis "void setUp(void){}". Do the same for tearDown.